# Apt contradicts itself about pip

Tags: apt, package-management, python, pip

Have ubuntu 22.04 under wsl2 on windows 11.
Want to install `psutil` package, following instructions on [git](https://github.com/giampaolo/psutil/blob/master/INSTALL.rst). Packages `gcc` and `python3-dev` are installed. Issuing the command

```
pip install --no-binary :all: psutil
```

produces response

```
Command 'pip' not found, but can be installed with:
sudo apt install python3-pip
```

but when I say

```
sudo apt install python3-pip
```

I get

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package python3-pip
```

What the...?

Comment: You need to enable the "Universe" repository - see duplicate above.

Comment: @ArturMeinild Yes it does, thanks!